# Sending a GET request with payload Volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I want to make a GET request using Volley in Android Studio and in this request I want to include a body.
The problem is that when using the GET request, the body in the server is `None` (I am using Flask). On the other side, when using the POST method, the body reaches the server correctly. This is my code:

```
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        String url = Globals.WINGS_VEHICLES_URL;

        JSONObject payload = new JSONObject();
        try {
            payload.put("user_id", Globals.USER_ID);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final String requestBody = payload.toString();
        System.out.println(requestBody);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                System.out.println(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() {
                return requestBody.getBytes();
            }


        };

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Is this a Volley restriction, or am I doing something wrong? Assume that I am using a `JSONObject` as body, non empty.

Comment: GET request doesn't allow a body to be sent. If you are using GET you should rather send it as url parameters.

Answer (score 0):

please check this answer
[HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

and Use POST Http method to send Body!!